# Javascript converting text from db to a hyperlink

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I started exploring ajax, and somehow I'm fine with it, not too hard and not easy just normal. Anyway I am having a difficulty with this project I have. It involves ajax, php, js, mysql. I am actually trying to copy Facebook's tagging style. When you tag someone in a post, the full name turns to a hyperlink that directs to the tag users profile. It's only a minor problem I feel, its just that I am new to JS as well. I did the rest already, but I am having a problem turning the text to a hyperlink with js. I want it in the putin_livesearch() the code.

This is my Code.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>FB TAG</title>

<style>

.namesearch {
    cursor:pointer;

}


</style>

<script type="text/javascript">


function putin_livesearch(fname, lname) 
{

//document.getElementById('searchbar').value = (fname + " " +lname);

//document.location.href='#'+ window.document.getElementById('searchbar').value = (fname);

window.document.location.href="#"+window.document.getElementById('searchbar').value;

}



function showResult(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";


    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
  <input id ="searchbar" name="wallpost" type="text" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)"  />
  <div id="livesearch"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**getuser.php**

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("place_main", $con);

$sql=" SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE firstname like '".$q."%' ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $fname = $row['firstname'];
  $lname = $row['lastname'];


  echo '<span class ="namesearch" onclick="putin_livesearch(\''.$fname.'\',\''.$lname.'\'  )"> '. $fname ." ". $lname .' </span><br />';


  //echo "<span class ='namesearch' onclick='putin_livesearch(" .$fname. ", " .$lname. " )'> " . $fname . " " . $lname . "</span><br />";
  }


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I guess what I am trying to is not possible. To the test I actually tried adding a value in a text area with an  tag. It does not turn it to a link. Did some inspecting in fb actually while tagging a friend with @ in the wallpost doesnt put it to a link, but afterwards when posting it does.

Answer (score 0):

on your php, just do something like this

```
echo "<a href='your-url-for-the-user'><span class ="namesearch" onclick="putin_livesearch(\''.$fname.'\',\''.$lname.'\'  )"> '. $fname ." ". $lname .' </span></a><br />";
```

Just manipulate it in the PHP then i'm pretty sure it will output the same in your frontend.

Comment: I already tried that actually. The problem with that is when I search a persons name. It will display the results with a hyperlink, problem with that is when I click it, it will redirect to a new page. Which is not what I want. I actually want it to be displayed in the textbox with the hyperlink.